# share data between functions inside controller in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I need to build a url using info from different controllers. inside my post controller I get the posts data from this:

Post Controller:

```
Data.get('posts').then(function(data){
    $scope.posts = data.data;
});
```

in the same controller I am getting site wide configs

```
configFactory.getconfigs().then(function(data){
    $rootScope.configs = data;
});
```

below that I am building a url

```
$scope.twitterUrl = "http://www.twitter.com?p1=$scope.posts.p1&p2=$rootScope.configs.p2&p3=$rootScope.configs.p3";
```

to put it all together:

```
app.controller('postsCtrl', function ($scope, $log, $http, $timeout, Data, Auth, TrackClicksFactory, $uibModal, $filter, $rootScope, configFactory, siteMsgFactory, $confirm) {

    Data.get('posts').then(function(data){
        $scope.posts = data.data;
    });

    configFactory.getconfigs().then(function(data){
        $rootScope.configs = data;
    });

    $scope.twitterUrl = "http://www.twitter.com?p1=$scope.posts.p1&p2=$rootScope.configs.p2&p3=$rootScope.configs.p3";

}
```

I am trying to get the data from both the $scope.posts and $rootScope.configs to build out my url.

I am sure this is easy but I have hit a wall. any help is much appreciated

Comment: Do you understand that the code inside `function(data)` runs **after** the line `$scope.twitterUrl = ...`? Read http://blog.ninja-squad.com/2015/05/28/angularjs-promises/ to understand what promises are, and then read the documentation of $q.all().

Comment: do you have a suggestion on how to achieve my goal?

Comment: What @JBNizet is alluding to is that you don't have the information you need to build the URL you want to construct due to the nature of promises.  Also, I'd add that you aren't interpolating the strings correctly here either since it'll munge the `$scope.posts.p1` as part of the actual string and not as a value unto itself.  There are solutions to this - notably using a service to perform the AJAX call - but a question that'd be worth asking would be, are you using ui-router with this at all?

Comment: @Jason yes. My suggestion is to read the article I linked to, and then the documentation of $q.all(), so that you understand what you're doing. Giving you the solution wouldn't teach you anything. And you'd still be stuck the next time you'll deal with promises, which happens **always** when using Angular.

Comment: sorry in my haste to write the url for this post I did not interpolate properly. I was building out the url in the html like this: `{{data.longurl | urlencode}}?utm_source={{configs[0].utm_source_a | urlencode}}_{{user.uid | urlencode}}&utm_medium={{configs[0].utm_medium | urlencode}}&utm_content={{data.guid | urlencode}}&utm_campaign={{configs[0].utm_campaign | urlencode}}` but twitter doesn't like it

Comment: Is there a way to chain these together? something like this? `{{ data.longurl+?utm_source=+configs[0].utm_source_a+_+user.uid+&utm_medium=+configs[0].utm_medium+&utm_content=+data.guid+&utm_campaign=+configs[0].utm_campaign+ | urlencode }}`

Comment: Duh! I figured it out. thank you for you help

Comment: @JBNizet For some reason I thought the promise's effect was only within the Data call. I will look at that link you sent. Thx